NFTables: stateful / dynamic rule
I'm looking for a way to simulate a network disruption at a very specific moment during cluster communication. When a special packet (no problems with matching this one) arrives at destination A, i need to "enable" a standalone rule dropping packets on another connection (service uses different connections for requests and replies). This would be trivially solved by a named counter, if only they could have been used in conditions. Is there a workaround to complete it within the NFT framework? If not, what would be close alternatives that could provide such a functionality?
